# Google Assistant voice command to geotag the current GPS coordinates onto a specified Google map

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm looking for a Google Assistant voice command that will geotag the current GPS coordinates onto a specified Google map. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Do you mean in "Google My Maps"? or Google Maps saved locations?

Comment: @Nicolas, either way would work.